# IDA Pro using Brew installed Python

Tags: idapython

Has anyone found a way to change the python installation used by IDA Pro? Using the system python on a Mac isn't terribly exciting.

Answer (score 2):

### Recompile IDAPython

[IDAPython](https://github.com/idapython/src) can be compiled from source and specify which installation of python to use. This was the recommendation from Hex-Rays support with the caveat that this isn't a supported configuration.